# i am no able to perform add-migration in

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using _Istudnet.Helper;
 

namespace _Istudnet.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        [Key]
  
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [mycustomeValidation(text:"Incadea")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
       
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public IFormFile simg { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Error : The property 'Student.simg' is of an interface type ('IFormFile'). If it is a navigation, manually configure the relationship for this property by casting it to a mapped entity type. Otherwise, ignore the property using the [NotMapped] attribute or 'Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store an image, you should use a byte array type:

```cs
public byte[] Simg { get; set; }
```

Now, when you read your `IFormFile` you can add it to your entity like so:

```
var file = request.FormFileFromSomewhere
using var ms = new MemoryStream();
file.CopyTo(ms);
myStudent.Simg = ms.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

- It is not best practice  depending your model class to anything related to presentation. Here IFormFile is related to **how** get files from user. Based on .Net documentation:

> IFormFile Interface
> Namespace: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http Assembly:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.dll Package:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref v7.0.0-rc.2.22476.2 Represents a file
> sent with the HttpRequest.

- So, it is better to change IFormFile to byte arrays(byte[]), your problem for migration will be solved and you have better model classes.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations; 
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema; 
using _Istudnet.Helper;

namespace _Istudnet.Models { 
  public class Student { 

     [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [mycustomeValidation(text:"Incadea")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
   
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public byte[] simg { get; set; }
  }
}
```

- For converting IFormfile to byte array you can use the following code in your controller:

```
// suppose _iformFile is type of IFormFile 


 var ms = new MemoryStream());    
 file.CopyTo(ms);
 byte[] fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
```

- The other solution (as mentioned in error message) is to ignore the propery (simg) from be included in database mapping by:

> ignore the property using the [NotMapped] attribute or 'Ignore' in
> 'OnModelCreating'.